# Чтобы mod rewrite не обрабатывал некоторые файлы и диретории

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте.

Есть файл в корне *zakaz.php* и директория *zakaz*. Файл принимает другие файлы *zakaz.php?filrname=имя.xls*, *mod rewrite* режет *?filrname=имя.xls*.

Что прописать в *.htaccess*, чтоб mod rewrite не трогал *zakaz.php* и директорию *zakaz*?
Сам в директивах полный нуб((

Сейчас RewriteEngine Off, чтоб работал *zakaz.php*.

Исходный *.htaccess* :

```html
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_reporting 0
php_value arg_separator.output "&amp;"
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
php_value short_open_tag on
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Если NetCat стоит в подпапке, например mysite, то
# RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mysite/netcat/require/e404.php
# в противном случае
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /netcat/require/e404.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} triumf.kdaksenov.ru
RewriteRule (.*) http://triumf-kf.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Comment: Покажите ваш .htaccess, так как вопрос ваш не ясен.

Comment: Да, опубликовал.

Comment: Попробуйте дописать к `[L,R=301]`, `[R=301,L]` флаг `QSA` -> `[L,R=301,QSA]`, `[R=301,L,QSA]` И в строке `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /netcat/require/e404.php` прописать флаги `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /netcat/require/e404.php [L,QSA]`.

Comment: Хм, вы формулировку вопроса сменили, не посмотрел :)

Comment: В `[E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]` и `[E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]` тоже можно флаг `QSA` дописать перед `E=` через запятую.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!